# How to insert nested array of data into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Currently I have an nested Array having three arrays (items,customer,address) that looks like the following when it output through

```
print_r($_POST);

Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 1
                    [item_price] => 2
                    [quantity] => 11
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 12
                    [item_price] => 13
                    [quantity] => 14
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 13
                    [item_price] => 14
                    [quantity] => 15
                )

            [3] =>; Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 16
                    [item_price] => 17
                    [quantity] => 18
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 18 
                    [item_price] => 38
                    [quantity] => 38
                )

        )

    [customer] => 111
    [address] => 171
)
```

I would like to insert this data into one table with each element value belonging to its respective field.

Currently **my php code** looks like the following

```
if(is_array($_POST)){
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

    $item_id = (int) $value['item_id'];
    $item_price = (int) $value['item_price'] ;
    $quantity = (int) $value['quantity'] ;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO orderItems(item_id, item_price, quantity) values ('$item_id', '$item_price', '$quantity')";
    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
    }
}
```

it's not working properly. I am new to this. Can anybody help?

Comment: You're a sitting duck with that code for SQL Injection attacks as the user submitted data isn't even escaped! **ALL** user submitted data should **ALWAYS** be validated to make sure that a user isn't trying to send garbage/junk/spam to the database. Also the mysql_* extension that you're using was **removed** from version 7 of PHP. Finally once user submitted data has been validated a prepared statment should **ALWAYS** be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You array lies inside the `items` array so rewrite you `foreach` loop like this :

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $key => $value){ 
//Remaining same code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orderItems(item_id, item_price, quantity) values ";

foreach($_POST['items'] AS $key=>$value)
{
    $item_id = (int) $value['item_id'];
    $item_price = (int) $value['item_price'] ;
    $quantity = (int) $value['quantity'] ;
    $sql .= "('$item_id', '$item_price', '$quantity'), ";
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);
mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
```

You have to use `$_POST['items']` in `foreach` block. Besides, you should try to create a single query using all these values and execute it once instead of executing again and again.